# How can I call a function defined in an Angular component in a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

In a `.ts` file, I have the following code

```
export class SomeClass {
    .
    .
    .
    public someMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to call this `someMethod` method in a `.js` file.

I tried

```
import { SomeClass } from '../../../../SomeClass';
.
.
.
SomeClass.someMethod();
```

but got the following error:

`someMethod is not a function`

Do I have to make the method `static`?

I prefer not because it calls other methods and I will have to make all of them `static`.

Can I create an instance of this class in the `.js` file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two solutions
either create instance of the class first then use public method like

```
let class = new SomeClass();
class.someMethod();
```

or make it static Method then your code will compile successfully

Answer (score 0):

possible way

u can build your ts files using build command and convert it to javascript then call it in your js file

this should work

Answer (score 0):

Futhermore create a instance of the class, you can also use some like

```
export function MyClass() {
    return new SomeClass()
}
```

Or if you neeed a constructor

```
export function MyClass(args) {
    return new SomeClass(args)
}
class SomeClass{
   constructor(arg){this._arg=arg}
}
```

You can in .ts

```
import { MyClass} from '...';

@Component({
   ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  MyClass=MyClass //<--if you want to use in .html
  ....
  myfunction(){
     MyClass.someMethod();
     //or
     const obj=MyClass();
     obj.someMethod();
  }
}
```

You can also, if only defined functions use a const

```
export const Utils{
    someFunction:()=>{console.log("hello"}
}
```

And then you use simply `Utils.someFunction()`